# VHDL assignment when ... else renders syntax error

Tags: syntax, vhdl

Simply, what would be wrong with this line?

```
zero <= '1' when alu_out = "00000000" else '0';
```

It is within a process. `zero` is `std_logic` and `alu_out` is `std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)`. Both are defined in the entity and the assignment is made in the architecture. The error is:

```
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at alu.vhd(27) near text "when";  expecting ";"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like using VHDL-2002 revision, where the concurrent conditional signal assign format can't be used as a statement in a process.

Try to enable VHDL-2008 revision support if the tool allows, otherwise use an `if` statement or write your own ternary function.

Also see this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16112469/2352082).

For Altera Quartus Prime ver. 15.1 the VHDL input version selection is shown in the figure below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I rewrote the code a bit so I could move the assignment out of the process, and this works. Using Quartus II 13.0.1. I don't know what versions of VHDL is supported. Anyway, your suggestion sounds good, and the problem is solved, so I'll accept this answer.

Comment: I think that Altera Quartus II ver. 13 also had some level of VHDL-2008 support, so you may try to enable it.  See added figure for how to enable it in Quartus Prime ver. 15.1, which is similar to that of ver. 13.1.